# Run old WordPress Page via local host

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I need to export posts and content from an old WordPress Site for a customer, to import on their new website. Is there a way to run the old website on my local host? Or is there a better way of getting the data.

Comment: you can export data from the live website (the old one), without the need to replicate it to localhost

Comment: It's just a PHP site, so sure, you can run it locally, or to avoid messing up your machine with wonky versions and other dependencies needed to run it, pop it in a virtual machine.

Comment: Should been more clear in my question but they already took down the old website thats why I was asking for a way by using local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access database, export cvs/xml file for post and content and then use this plugin to import to new Wordpress site.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built-in Posts and Content exporter I would use something like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to backup the whole site and migrate to your localhost to use the built-in Posts and Content exporter.

But if you still have access to a working old site, I would just export from there and import on the new site

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it is not that easy as they already took down the old website so no way of exporting it via Duplicator or the built-in file export. In hopes they still have a copy of their website and database I was wondering if it's possible to host the site via local host. Should have been more clear in my question